# GIT: how to commit in two branches using cherry-pick

Tags: java, git, branch, push, cherry-pick

I have one local commit (for example, at `branch1` branch) and I need to apply it to another branch (eg. `branch2`). I know that I have to use the

```
git cherry-pick
```

command but I really cant find out by myself how the command should finally look. Help me please and sorry for my English.

**UPD:** I've read [this link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html), but I still cant understand how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[git cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) should be as easy as:

```
git checkout targetBranch
git cherry-pick <SHA1>
```

(with `<SHA1>` the SHA1 of the commit you want to apply)

In your case:

```
git checkout branch2
git cherry-pick branch1
```

See [this blog post](https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/) or [this post](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-cherry-pick-changes-with-git) for example.

You have more illustrations in "[CHERRY-PICKING EXPLAINED](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html)":

[image: http://think-like-a-git.net/assets/images2/reachability-example.png]

If you were at node `H` in this graph, and you typed `git cherry-pick E` (yes, you'd actually type part or all of the SHA for the commit, but for simplicity's sake, I'll just use the labels that are already here), you'd wind up with a copy of commit `E`—let's call it "`E prime`" or `E'`—that pointed to `H` as its parent, like so:

[image: http://think-like-a-git.net/assets/images2/cherry-pick-example-1.png]